# How to use import from modules instead of destructuring

Tags: eslint

I want to prohibit imports from the main library. For example:

`import { get, set } from 'lodash';`
or
`import { ActionCard, Button } from 'app/components/GlobalUI';`

Instead, allow only imports directly from the module. For example:
`import get from 'lodash/get'; import set from 'lodash/set';`
or
`import ActionCard from 'app/components/GlobalUI/ActionCard'; import Button from 'app/components/GlobalUI/Button';`

I'm trying to configure ESLint, but so far without success.